# How to see exact same feature in pre-machine learning diagnosis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to see, is my data is possible to high accuracy or not based on exact same feature (not target variable), here's my data:

```
X1 X2 X3 X4 y
2  3  4  5  1
5  2  3  2  0
2  3  4  5  1
5  2  2  2  0
4  3  2  5  1
2  3  4  5  0
5  2  2  2  0
```

What I want to see is

```
X1 X2 X3 X4 y
2  3  4  5  1
2  3  4  5  1
2  3  4  5  0
5  2  2  2  0
5  2  2  2  0
```

So I can give diagnosis on this  exact same feature, any sugestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [**`pd.DataFrame.duplicated`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html).  Include the parameter `keep=False` in order to identify all rows that have a duplicate.

```
df[df.drop('y', 1).duplicated(keep=False)]

   X1  X2  X3  X4  y
0   2   3   4   5  1
2   2   3   4   5  1
3   5   2   2   2  0
5   2   3   4   5  0
6   5   2   2   2  0
```

Notice that I `drop('y', 1)` in order to drop the `'y'` column.  The point of this was to restrict the evaluation of duplication to non-`'y'` columns. 
 We could have also used the `subset` parameter of `duplicated`.

```
df[df.duplicated(['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4'], keep=False)]

   X1  X2  X3  X4  y
0   2   3   4   5  1
2   2   3   4   5  1
3   5   2   2   2  0
5   2   3   4   5  0
6   5   2   2   2  0
```